# Import Multiple Category with Product CSV

Tags: category, csv, category-listing, import-products

I am trying to import product through Magento 2 Admin Panel using CSV file. My CSV file looks like below

[image]

I have categories like **All Category/Bikes, Scooters & Ride-Ons** and **All Category/Fashion Accessories, All Category/Fashion Accessories/Ladies**.

If I import this CSV file I got categories like.

- All Category/Bikes
- Scooters & Ride-Ons
- All Category/Fashion Accessories
- All Category/Fashion Accessories/Ladies

I tried with below CSV file.

[image]

I got below result.

[image]

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have got a solution for this. Use `&#44;` in category name and in CSV. It will look the same on frontend as well as admin as shown in the attached image:[image]

[image]

Comment: Terrible answer. It's a hack, and will almost certainly cause more problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The commas in your category names must either be within a double-quote enclosed string (`"All Category/Bikes, Scooters & Ride-Ons"`) or escaped. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file